# Edge Browser Becomes Default Browser For NFC Links

Tags: nfc, microsoft-edge

Any guess on why this happens?

Android with multiple browsers - None is the default
Scan an NFC tag with a link and user is prompted with browsers to select from

Add Edge - Still no browser is the default
Scan tag and Edge is opened - no prompt